# Is it true that nonnegative independent random variables with sum of expectations$=\infty$ also has sum$=\infty$ a.s.?

Tags: probability-theory

I wonder if it's true that if $X_1,...,X_n,...$ are independent and nonnegative random variables and that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty E[X_i]=\infty$, then $\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i=\infty$ a.s.?

I suspect so because its true if $X_i=1_{A_i}$, which is the 2nd Borel-Cantelli lemma. If $X_i=exp(\lambda_i)$, then its also true, which is a property of exponential random variables. However, I couldn't work out a proof for the above statement, so I wonder if there are counterexamples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a counterexample, let $X_i = 3^i$ with probability $\frac1{3^i}$, and $0$ otherwise. Then $\mathbb E[X_i]= 1$ and therefore $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb E[X_i] = \infty$.

However, we have $\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i = 0$ with probability at least $1 - \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{3^i} = \frac12$ (actually, with probability about $0.56$).